# is the following statement correct?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if I am using the word **"clear"** appropriately, and if this sentence is correct:

> I added a screen shot below of the message to be more clear.

---

**context:** The context is that I have a tecnical problem and I added a screen shot to explain better the issue, but I am not sure if that sentence is correct

Comment: What do you want to imply?

Comment: the context is that I have a tecnical problem and I added a screen shot to explain better the issue, but I am not sure if that sentence is correct.

Comment: I am a learner as you, but I think there are better sentences to say that

Comment: For example, In order to make the message clearer, I added a screen shot at the bottom. lets wait for masters

Comment: Why comma? Do you mean: "l added the screenshot of the message..."? As you can see the sentence is not quite correct - people struggle to understand what you mean.

Comment: ok I agree with you I will remove the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "clearer"

"More clear" is fine too.

Personally I tend to just say, "I have a screenshot, attached." without saying anything about clarity because it is usually understood that an attachment or screenshot is meant to clarify something.

Comment: I agree with just leaving it off. "I added a screenshot of the message below" with "for clarity" being implied.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I finally decided to write:  ***"to be more clear, I attached a screen shot of it"*** to show my politeness, with the support team, but I appreciate your support.